# Google Script equal to date?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a new spreadsheet that is set to give me a week ahead reminder for a review date. I'm trying to do a very basic test of checking if the date 7 days ahead from today is equal to the date that is on the spreadsheet.

When debugging this I noticed the times get added to the date so I set the times to be 00:00:00 to try and get a match, this still does not work.

```
function main(){
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate()+7);
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  for (var j = 53; j < lastrow-1; j++){
    var Staff = StaffObjects[j];
    var name = Staff.firstName + " " + Staff.surname;
    var onemonth = Staff.oneMonth;
    onemonth.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if (d == onemonth){
      messagePT2+= name + "is due there one month review on " + onemonth + "<br>";
    }
  }
}
```

When debugging this, the values are exactly the same:

d = Fri Mar 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT)
onemonth = Fri Mar 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT)

However this does not register as a match, why is this and how could i go about fixing this? Lastly. Some dates have different time zones such as this.. Wed May 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) is there any way to check for just the date?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing date objects for equality does not work like that. It's better if you convert them to numbers (or strings) to compare. Try this:

```
if (d.getTime() == onemonth.getTime()){
  //etc
}
```

Note that when comparing with `>` and `<` and variants it does work (because it uses `valueOf`).

Comment: Several minutes after asking this, I figured this out aha!

Answer (score 4):

In the comparison you should use `.getTime()` in each part because there are 2 different objects that will never be equal even if their value are equal.

So this condition should work :

```
if (d.getTime() == onemonth.getTime()){
```